# Question from non-technical business user: Storage on phone vs. storage on cloud

Tags: android, ios, local-storage, message, cloud-storage

Is there a way for a mobile messaging app to hold messages sent and messages received on the app without a 3rd party (e.g. AWS) having to continually store these messages?  My purpose is to bring down my costs.  I would still pay for data ingestion and data egression, but I'm hoping to not have to hold the costs of storage, but rather that users can store their important messages on their own phones, and delete them when they're ready.  I'm imagining this is how the iPhone's Messages app works.  In my mind, this is like creating a photos app, combined with a messages app, etc.

Any verification that this is possible or tips/links for such a practice would be very appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure Stack overflow is the place for this kind of question, Stack Overflow is for programming topic questions, but to answer it seems complicated, what would happen if one messager is not connected when a message is sent to him, do you keep the message in your Database or not ?

Comment: Good question - I'm imagining that, like iMessages, the receiver's app lets the sender's app know when the message has been delivered.  The sender's app would attempt to send.  If the receiver's app doesn't signal that the message is delivered, then the messenger would attempt connecting at a later time until the message is sent.

Comment: Maybe I could hold in my database a signal from the sender's app to the receiver's app that a message is pending (as opposed to holding the message itself).  That way the receiver's app could receive a "message-pending" notification and commence connecting with the sender's app in order to receive the message.  Do you think something like this would work?

Comment: And apologies if Stack Overflow is the wrong place for this type of question.  I see Stack Overflow as a community of knowledgeable technologists who can help me identify the possibilities enabled by programming.  I'm grateful for help on the topic!

Comment: What I think is that you should build your messaging app the right way, with a database that stores the messages, that would avoid complexity, because what you're trying to do is not having a database and you end up storing info on what message has been delivered. If you want to save space, delete each message once they have been sent, but beware if your user connects on an other device he will not be able to retrieve them.

Comment: Also you should check that storage is not that expensive unless you are storing digital assets like photo or video, but text is almost nothing.

Comment: That's a great idea.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome Nick.

Comment: It's video assets that I'd be storing.  I'm hoping to provide high quality video in the messaging, but that get's expensive pretty quickly with storage :/

Comment: You can use Firebase Database or Firebase CloudFirestorem it is free for the first 3 projects. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. A server located in the cloud can simply transfer data between two simultaneously connected clients, without ever needing to store that data to disk.

A portion of the data will have to be exist in memory of some form (e.g., RAM), at least momentarily. Taken to the extreme, this space requirement could be reduced to a single byte.

Storage is not particularly expensive, even for this use case. Nevertheless, if your architecture doesn't require any storage, then there's no reason to buy any.

I do not have any good links for you. I don't even know if this concept has a name. But you should understand that this is a very basic concept of computer communication/buffering.

If you've noticed that messaging services tend to like to keep your data in the cloud, well, (forgive my cynicism, but) that's probably just so they can mine it at their convenience.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the help!  

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you believe it is correct :)